# Ruby Grape Reactor gets blocked

Tags: ruby, blocked, reactor, ruby-grape

I am creating an API using Ruby Grape and I face the following problem.
When there is a new GET request, a large amount of data is requested which takes long time and in the meanwhile Reactor is blocked and no new requests can be handled until the request is finished.
Code is quite straight forward:

```
class API < Grape::API
  resource :users do
    get do
      get_users()
    end
  end
end
```

get_users connects to another system by TCP and gets a large amount of data converted to JSON. This is done using a 3rd party gem.
What would be the best option to handle this type of situations?

Answer (score 0):

I think of two options:

1. Set up passenger/unicorn etc. with enough workers to handle concurrent requests.
2. If this is not enough: re-make API logic so that long operations will break up to two calls: first - leave a request, second - check for completion/retrieve result.

Also, if it is suitable - you could cache the result of get_users()

Comment: Thanks Yuriy.
1. I am using Thin. I was thinking an architecture like NginX+HAProxy+Thin with several instances. I will check also Passenger and Unicorn.
2. I tried to do something similar with EM.defer. Do you think that's the good approach?
Caching is something I had not thought about. I will also check.
But I think I prefer you point number 2.

Comment: Actually I meant another thing. Here is an example:
1. Client calls get users
2. App saves this request, returning generated request secret key to client
3. App makes get_users() via delayed_job or similar
4. App saves the result of get_users() associated with request secret key
5. Client calls get users with secret key
6. App returns the result associated with the key.
App should return not_ready, when get_users() hasn't finished yet.
App should expire keys and results.
The cons is that client has to change it's logic. So this is only for really long operations like reports generating.

Comment: I understand now. I do not really like that approach as it requires the client to change its logic as you mention. I will test your point 1 and see what I can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your application performs a long-running blocking I/O operation. To handle these kinds of workloads well, your system needs to support high I/O concurrency.

Traditional single-threaded multi-process systems such as Phusion Passenger open source and Unicorn are not suitable for these kinds of workloads. The amount of concurrency they can handle is limited by the number of processes. This problem is documented on Unicorn's [philosophy page](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/PHILOSOPHY.html), section "Just Worse in Some Cases", or on the recent Phusion article about [tuning Phusion Passenger's concurrency](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/03/12/tuning-phusion-passengers-concurrency-settings/).

While Thin is in theory capable of handling high I/O concurrency due to its evented I/O model, applications and frameworks must be explicitly written to take advantage of this. Few frameworks do this. Neither Rails nor Sinatra support evented I/O. Cramp supports it and there was another new evented framework whose name I've forgotten. But it seems Grape does not support evented I/O.

The solution would be to switch to a multithreading-capable application server, which are also capable of supporting high I/O concurrency. One such application server is [Phusion Passenger 4 Enterprise](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise), which supports a hybrid multithreaded/multiprocess model. Multithreading is concurrency, while multiprocess is for stability and the ability to leverage multiple CPU cores. The Phusion blog [describes optimal concurrency settings for different workloads.](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/03/12/tuning-phusion-passengers-concurrency-settings/)